# best way to archive records

Tags: sql-server, database-design, archive

I have a table which named "RawNews" with the following fields:

```
[NewsID] [decimal](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Text] [ntext] NULL,
[RegDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RegTime] [time](0) NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[Tags] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[SecurityLevelID] [smallint] NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
[DelDate] [nchar](10) NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
```

and another table named "UsedNews" which has the same fields plus
some other fields.
and there are some other tables realted to these tables like uploads,images,newsGroups,NewsRooms,Users and etc.

in the RawNews I have 100 records each day. and these 100 recors for UsedNews.
these information should be kept for like eternity.
I wanted to ask you to advice me for a good way too make archive of records, so the search and filtering performance remains good.
and another question: I have log table which logs every event in the system, should i keep it in a seperate database or not?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [table partitioning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx) to solve this. The RegDate can be used to determine whether the  records should be moved to the archive group or not.

You could choose to place the archive table on a separate disk so when searches on it might take place, it'll have the least possible effect on the rest of the "live" database.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this..

1. You can use appropriate "Replication" functionality of SQL Server. In your case Snapshot Replication type seems appropriate for more details [Click](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151832.aspx)
2. You can create windows service to move data from RawNews to UsedNews.
3. You can create an exe to move data and using windows task scheduler you can call that exe at specific time when there is less load on server.

Comment: What do you think about a flag to tell if the record is archived, some indexes and maybe partition the table depending on this flag?

Comment: thanks bro. but you miss understood my question. in my scenario one RawNews could be used in several newsGroups ( one "usedNews" record for each newsgroup).